# Basic jQuery Selector Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select a checkbox with value "foo" and check it. I tried this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$("input[type='checkbox'][value='foo']").attr('checked', true);</script>
```

But nothing seems to be happening. Is there something I'm missing? I'm very new at this.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: This is on SquareSpace so it doesn't really show me errors unfortunately. Does the code look correct?

Comment: Yes, it should work, but place it inside document.ready.http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you be calling this before your [`.ready()`](http://jsfiddle.net/4d3krgbs/) event? This example works fine

```
<input type="checkbox" value="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" value="notFoo" />
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox'][value='foo']").attr('checked', true);
});
```

### [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4d3krgbs/)

So esentially, in your example if you wish to keep it looking as is, just wrap it as such

```
<script>$(function() { $("input[type='checkbox'][value='foo']").attr('checked', true); })</script>
```

Comment: Oh, that's exactly what was happening! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this `$(":checkbox[value='foo']").prop("checked","true");`

```html
<script>
$(function(){
$(":checkbox[value='foo']").prop("checked","true");
});
</script>
```